# Coercing NSNull value to nil in shouldSetValue:atKeyPath restkit

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

i'm having a web service that that collects the company names and phone numbers from the database. But sometimes a phone number is not provided. When i try to map the phone number to the object with restkit 'im getting a warning  that value is nil sometimes. then i get the warning message:

```
Coercing NSNull value to nil in shouldSetValue:atKeyPath: -- should be fixed.
```

any suggestions how to map nil to NSNull?

this is my header file of my customerrealtion class (.h):

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

 @interface CustomerRelation : NSObject

 #pragma private fields


 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *companyName;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phoneNumber;

 @end
```

implementation file of customer relation class (.m)

```
 #import "CustomerRelation.h"

 @implementation CustomerRelation



-(BOOL)ValidatecompanyName:(id*)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
   NSLog(@"error");

}
-(BOOL)validatephoneNumber:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
if (*ioValue == nil) {
    if (outError != NULL) {

              }
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

@end
```

this is where i do the mapping:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

RKObjectManager * client = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1"]];
RKObjectMapping *articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"Companyname": @"companyName",
                                                     @"Phonenumber": @"phoneNumber"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *rkresponsedesc =  [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"customers" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[client addResponseDescriptor:rkresponsedesc];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:@"test.php" parameters:nil];



RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [client objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                                                   [self mappingSuccess:mappingResult];

                                                                               } failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                   NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                                               }];
[client enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];



MainViewController *viewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

}

```
 - (void)mappingSuccess:(RKMappingResult*)mappingResult
{
    NSLog(@"Success block: %@", mappingResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found why the validate methods were never called. 
the error was in the line

```
RKObjectMapping *customerRelationMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
```

what should get the class instead:

```
  RKObjectMapping *customerRelationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that error I guess you're using an old version of RestKit and that you should update.

That said you should be able to tie into this with KVC validation which RestKit supports. If you implement `validateValue:forKey:error:` on your destination model object you can verify and edit the value being set for any key.

Comment: iam using the latest restkit (0.20). Can you give me an example how to implement the validate value:forkey:error: ? or point me to the correct documentation page? i can' find it in their documentation. thx

Comment: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/16eb7ed46ec17721c073ff9ebb14bea58ce4848d/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md#key-value-validation and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB

Comment: i tried to implement the validate value, but i'm still getting this warning, also if i set a breakpoint to the validatePhonenumber method , it does not go trough it. i added more code to my original question

Comment: You haven't spelt the method names correctly. It should be `validatePhoneNumber` (Capital letters are important).

Comment: Putting the method name in capitals sadly doen't help. any other suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: is a validation invoked automatically by restkit or should i do something special for that?

Comment: If you get the naming correct it is called automatically. If you get the naming wrong it will never be called.